# How to assign type to graphQL return?

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I'm working on a small project with Apollo Angular to work with a graphQL server.

I have a simple component that does a query to the server and it returns a string:

```js
const GET_HELLO = gql`
  query ExampleQuery {
    hello
  }
`

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ti4-automation';
  public something: string = "Old world..."

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apollo.query({
      query: GET_HELLO
    }).subscribe((
      { data, loading}) => {
        console.log(data, loading)
      })
  }
}
```

This works, the issue is that the type of `data` is `unknown`:

[image]

Which TypeScript (and me) do not like.

How would I add a type to the `data` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u can use codegen package to create ur queries and mutation types.
But for now u should add type when u use apollo query method
like this:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
this.apollo.query<YourType>({
  query: GET_HELLO
}).subscribe((
  { data, loading}) => {
    console.log(data, loading)
  })
}
```

also I recommend to read https://the-guild.dev/graphql/apollo-angular/docs/data/queries.